# Does "the alphabet of the language of propositional logic" have no function symbols, relation symbols, and constants?

Tags: logic, computer-science, propositional-calculus

In Ebbinghaus' Mathematical Logic, II.2.1 on p14 says that the alphabet of a first order language contains function symbols, relation symbols, and constants, whereas I don't see these symbols in "the alphabet of the language of propositional logic" in XI.4.1 on p201.

- So is it true that "the alphabet of the language of propositional logic"  has no  function symbols, relation symbols, and constants?
- By "the" in  "the alphabet of the language of propositional logic", is there only one language of propositional logic, while there are many first order languages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly. Propositional logic has only propositional variables and connectives (and parentheses).

See page 201, **Def.4.1**.

You may have different languages according  to the set of basic connectives used.